# How to write a random variable is not distributed as N(0,1)

Tags: notation

I was wondering if the symbol $\not\sim$ (i.e., not tilde) could be used to express that a random variable $X$ is not distributed as a normal distribution with a mean of $0$ and variance of $1$. For instance, is this appropriate:   $$X\not\sim N(0,1)$$

Or is it more common to say: $$X \text{ is not } X\sim N(0,1)$$

I need a way to express it in a symbolic form to be as succinct as possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the most common way would be to just use words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen anyone say this, but that first notation seems to have an obvious meaning to me, so I would think that is a perfectly reasonable way to write this.  (The second notation seems flawed to me, since it says "$X \text{ is not }X$" which is a contradiction.)